# Ubuntu Grub recognises MacOS but cannot boot up

Tags: ubuntu, osx, grub2

I tried a little experiment on installing MacOS on a non Mac Hardware Laptop...
Got this far as to put the MacOS Install ISO on to an HFS+ partition but the machine needs to boot this up for the actual install to happen.
 
The Machine also has Windows 8.1 and Ubuntu --
The Ubuntu grub2 fully sees and recognizes the MacOS HFS+ partition and provides MacOS boot entries for this .... but when selected ... just wont boot up the MacOS ...
 
Any one has tried booting up MacOS from Ubuntu on a Non-Mac Hardware ? what needs to be done ?

Comment: Is that MacOS X? Do you use UEFI boot?

Comment: Yup that is MacOS X Snow Leopard -- have tried both UEFI boot as well as legacy.

Comment: MacOS X needs UEFI boot. Do you have UEFI GRUB installed? Have you tried using UEFI boot menu instead of GRUB?